# Text not changing when using .innerHTML and var

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
var name = document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
name.innerHTML = "XYZ";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Hello</h1>

  <input type="checkbox">

  <button style=":active color:red;">Click Me</button>

  <ul>
    <li class="list">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list">Second</li>
    <li class="list">Third</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

So, this is the code for a website, and I wanted to change the text of the last element of the document - "Third" changes to "XYZ".

When I use the following code, the text does not change.

```
var name=document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
name.innerHTML="XYZ";
```

However, when I use this:

```
document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML="XYZ";
```

The text on the website, immediately changes. Why is this happening? All I have done is just split the code in two lines instead of writing it in one.

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier to maintain if you just used `document.querySelector("li:last-of-type");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the global scope, [the `name` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is predefined and can only be assigned strings.

You can:

- Use `let` instead of `var` to shadow (instead of mapping onto) global variables.
- Use a JS module instead of a regular script to get module scope instead of global scope
- Use an IIFE to get function scope instead of global scope
- Use a different variable name

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` or `const` instead of `var`

and this would be easier:

```
let name = document.querySelector("li.list:last-child");
name.textContent = 'XYZ'
```

if you just want to change the text content then use textContent instead of innerHTML